# How does one download the CiviCRM 4.6 User Guide in PDF?

Tags: documentation

Civi Peeps.

Almost embarrassed to ask this ask this question, but only almost.

On its documentation site, under "About this book", Civi states:

"This book is freely available to read online and download in multiple formats."

I haven't yet found a way to download the entire guide in PDF or any other format.

The link to that page is here:

http://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.6/introduction/about-this-book/

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Comment: that is a really good question ;-) as per this blog i assumed a pdf option would be part of the switch - but i also am not finding a link. https://civicrm.org/blogs/michael-mcandrew/moving-civicrms-user-and-administrator-guide-gitbook-or-readthedocs

Answer (score 4):

Looks like PDF isn't available, but a downloadable copy of those docs in Markdown format is available from the Github repository linked in the top right of http://docs.civicrm.org ("Edit in Github").

[github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide) => [Download ZIP](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-user-guide/archive/master.zip)

This (zipped) download is in a quite readable format, even in a plain text editor. Which tool you view it in will determine whether some features like inline images are displayed; search for a Markdown editor for your OS if you want support for images / visual formatting.

Bonus: it's a great format to submit docs fixes! Perhaps your first submission will improve on "This book is freely available to read online and download in multiple formats." in `docs/index.md` :)

In that linked Github repo, you'll see a `mkdocs.yml` file indicating that CiviCRM's docs are built via [MkDocs](http://www.mkdocs.org/). According to [this FAQ answer on readthedocs.org](http://docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/builds.html?highlight=pdf#mkdocs),  the Markdown/MkDocs format doesn't provide us with automatic PDF generation (yet) but it does make it easy for people to contribute improvements.